# How many queries can you do (concretely, not asymptotically) for a balanced Feistel network with 7 rounds?

Tags: feistel-network

In [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-45146-4_30.pdf) Patarin says that:
"for every $\epsilon > 0$, when $m \ll 2^{n(1 - \epsilon)}$ ... for 7 rounds or more it is secure against all adaptive chosen plaintext attacks" where m is the number of queries that the adversary can evaluate.

What concretely is meant by $m \ll 2^{n(1 - \epsilon)}$?

For instance, to have statistical security $2^{-\sigma}$ (e.g. $\sigma = 40$) concretely how many queries can be evaluated?

Comment: define statistical security

Comment: How would you even define << concretely? It's sort an asymptotic idea.

Comment: @kodlu Where statistical security is the advantage of an adversary has in the Chosen Plaintext Attack game, when they are able to make $m$ queries and have unlimited computational resources.

Comment: ok so you want the advantage to be upper bounded by $2^{-40}.$

Comment: @kodlu Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The linked paper is missing a lot of proof details. In any case, it seems impossible to say anything concrete for finite $n$ due to the existence of terms in $O(\cdot)$ notation in the bounds. You simply do not know how large those implied constants are.

Comment: Yeah--the missing proof details is a lot of the problem... In principle if the details of the proof were there I should be able to go through and figure out what the constants are in the $\mathcal{O}()$ notation. But since they are omitted, I was hoping someone out there might know of a place that someone had gone through and calculated the constants. Or if not, a place where I can find the full proof so I can go through and try to figure out the constants myself.

Comment: Did it not reference where the *full* version is, in the paper? These kinds of arguments are usually asymptotic.

Comment: see also here https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43870/is-3-rounds-feistel-enough-for-making-prp?rq=1 for a related question and the followup comment which has links to more  but based on @fgrieu's comment I don't hold high hopes that you'll get what you want.

Comment: Yes, citation 15. "Extended version of this paper. Available from the author." I was hoping to find a source online, but I can contact the author.

Comment: @Daniel-耶稣活着 : The question's paper is cited in [_Chapter 3
The H-Coefficient Method_](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-49530-9_3) of Valerie Nachef, Jacques Patarin, Emmanuel Volte's [_Feistel Ciphers: Security Proofs and Cryptanalysis_](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-49530-9). Glancing at it from a distance, it looks like a clarified re-exposition. Not that I get much of it.